# how to add/convert certificate file into pkcs12 file

Tags: java, x509certificate, pkcs#12, jks, cer

I have received the three certificates(.CER files) to access the production server. How I am going to add/convert these certificates into PKCS12 file.

Comment: Do you also have the private key? In a keystore?

Comment: For accessing the production environment I have received ONLY the three certificates(no keys/alias etc). But in my development environment, I am having the keystore file, alias and password for the keystore and PKSC12 file available.

Comment: How are you going to use the PKCS12 file?  Are these certificates the server certificate and the certificate chain up to a CA cert?

Comment: Code is working fine in development environment where I am having couple of certificates(PKCS12) for signing and encryption to send messages to the server. And self-signed certificate(JKS) which I have used to generate the truststore file. Now I have received the three certificates(.CER files) to access the production server. How I am going to add/convert these certificates into PKCS12 file and truststore file.

Answer (score 2):

First export your certificates to a keystore and then import the keystore as a pkcs12 file. If you jave java installed you can use keytool command to accomplish both. 

1) /jre/bin/keytool -importcert -alias cert1 -keystore keystore.jks -file Cert1.cer
2) /jre/bin/keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -srcalias cert1 -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

Similar steps can be done using openssl too.

Comment: I am running the first command keytool -export -alias cert1 -keystore new_truststore.jks -file ProduCert.cer
It's giving me error file new_truststore.jks doesn't exists. 
If I give my development environment JKS file then I get alias cert1 doesn't exists.

Comment: This is what I have done:
1. keytool -importcert -alias medicare -keystore storeskey.jks -file ProduCert.cer

2. keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore storeskey.jks -srcalias medicare -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

And I am getting the below exception:
Problem importing entry for alias medicare: java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported.
Entry for alias medicare not imported.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and when it say's 'Do you want to quit the import process? [no]:'  keep typing 'no'. It finally said: Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 2 entries failed or cancelled.

It worked and all my certs were imported into the new format correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just used a older version of keytool executable and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

the server on which you sign your certification $(hostname -f).pem should have the same java version as the nodes you plan to import cert like the following:

$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -importcert -alias $(hostname -f) -file /opt/cloudera/security/pki/$(hostname -f).pem -keystore /opt/cloudera/security/pki/$(hostname -f).jks

if you take lower version on the server to sign your certification but you take new java version on the nodes for TLS/SSL, you will see the warning.